# Disable MaskedTextBox sound

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, maskedtextbox

I use a `MaskedTextBox` control to facilitate the entry of dates in my project. I have `mtb.BeepOnError` set to `false`. However, it makes a generic beep whenever the 'Enter' key or 'Esc' key is pressed, and this is undesirable for my application.

This seems to be the default behaviour for the MTB, so is there any way to change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
void mtb_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter | e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape) {
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: This works swimmingly. Thank you! I was too stuck on changing a property, and didn't think of a workaround.